# How to Dynamically add gates in Laravel?

Tags: php, laravel-5, php-7

How to Dynamically add gates in Laravel?
I built my CMS on laravel, and  it support plugins. Plugin can add menu item in dashboard,  some page , routes etc. I need use gate for protect edit / delete / add / change page for example, that an authorized user did not create.
So I need that each plugin can  Dynamically add  this permissions (view /add/edit/update/delete/)
How I can do this?
And btw plugin locate in APP/Plugins folder.
And Admin can attach this permission to some roles http://prntscr.com/kidnxz
https://pastecode.xyz/view/bcb9d00f here example table that I have.
and problem that I need also add in permissions table permission 
I use laravel 5.6

Here example of simple plugin pastecode.xyz/view/75d2fa28 Calls boot when plugin loaded And onActivate when user activate this plugin

I'm looking for something like dynamic Policies

or like  https://octobercms.com/docs/plugin/registration

```
  'permissions' => ['acme.blog.*'],
```

Comment: Usually other CMSs have "hooks" and the underlying framework calls each plugin hook during the appropriate bootup phase. For example you can have a "boot" hook in one of your service provider which calls any "boot hook" defined in plugins that initializes them appropriately. I know this is a broad comment but this is a broad question so if you want something more specific you need to share details on how your implementation works .

Comment: Here example of simple plugin https://pastecode.xyz/view/75d2fa28
Calls boot when plugin loaded 
And onActivate when user activate this plugin

Answer (score 1):

As far as I understood from your question your CMS may has several gates that you do not want to define separate gates for each of them. You may try `before` method to define dynamic gates.

```
public function boot(){

      Gate::before(function (User $user, $ability) {
            Gate::define($ability, function (User $user) use ($ability) {
                return $user->hasPermission($ability);
            });
      });

}
```

In the above example `hasPermission` is a method in User model that check if user has the right permission/ability.

Now you can use it like this in controller:

```
Gate::authorize('CUSTOME_ABILITY');
```

Or as middleware:

```
Route::get('/', function (Request $request) {
    // your code
})->can('CUSTOME_ABILITY');
```

Answer (score 0):

You can use `Gate::policy(PolicyTarget::class, PolicyImplementation::class)` to register a new gate policy inside your plugin.

Assume you have a policy target being e.g. a user (bad example maybe).

Create a policy with e.g. `php artisan make:policy UserInteractsWithBlogPolicy`

```
class UserInteractsWithBlogPolicy {
   // Boilerplate and custom code
}
```

Then you can register this when the plugin boots:

```
 public function boot() {
            // TODO: Implement boot() method.
            $this->enableRoutes();
            $this->enableViews();
            \Gate::policy(User::class, UserInteractsWithBlogPolicy::class); 

}
```

Then you can use the normal policy rules like e.g.

```
 $user->can("view", Blog::find(1));
```

Or basically do whatever can be done according to https://laravel.com/docs/5.6/authorization#authorizing-actions-using-policies

Comment: Ok, thanks. Now, how I can get all methods registered polices? I need this for generate list permissions like this http://prntscr.com/kiio2w
I need something like Gate::abilities() but it not returns permission that registered in UserInteractsWithBlogPolicy

Comment: That's a bit more complex. My guess is you should create a Policy base class that subclasses need to implement to return these and each policy you create should have this implemented so you can retrieve them when needed. There's no built-in laravel way to do this as far as I know so you probably need to write this on your own for this particular project. Alternatively you could possibly use [reflection](http://php.net/manual/en/reflectionclass.getmethods.php) to get a list of all methods in a policy